# JSP data into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have data in my JSP file read from the servlet. I need this data in javascript for validation. How can I get this data in javascript. Ive tried sending this data to a method in javascript. but it is not working. here is my jsp file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
-->
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ page
    import="com.thbs.mis.common.bo.User,
    com.thbs.mis.common.config.RoleConstants,
    com.thbs.mis.common.bo.BusinessUnits,
    java.util.List,
        java.util.Iterator,
    java.util.ArrayList,java.util.Date"%>

<%@page
    import="com.thbs.mis.spotexcellenceaward.bo.SpotExcellenceAwardBO,
    com.thbs.mis.gsrreporthr.bo.GsrSlab"%>
    <%!List<GsrSlab> slabList = new ArrayList<GsrSlab>(); %> 

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>View Spot Excellence Award</title>
<link href="/RMS/CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/CSS/cal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="SCRIPTS/calendar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="SCRIPTS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SCRIPTS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#coolmenu {
    width: 170px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

* html #coolmenu {
    /*IE only rule, to negate the padding below IE includes in menu width.*/
    width: 160;
}

#coolmenu a {
    font: bold 11px Verdana;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #209C96;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

html>body #coolmenu a { /*Non IE rule*/
    width: auto;
}

#coolmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #209C96;
    color: white;
}
</style>


<script src="SCRIPTS/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SCRIPTS/autoCompleteV1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SCRIPTS/ajax.js"></script>

<script>
function myFunction() 
{

   var flag=true;
    var year = document.getElementById("year").options[document.getElementById("year").selectedIndex].text;
    var slab =document.getElementById("slab").options[document.getElementById("slab").selectedIndex].text;

    if(year==="-select year-" && slab==="-select slab-")
    {
        alert("Please select year and slab");
        flag=false;
    }
    if(year==="-select year-" && slab!=="-select slab-")
    {
        alert("Please select year");
        flag=false;
    }
    if(slab==="-select slab-" && year!=="-select year-")
    {
        alert("Please select slab");
        flag= false;
    }

    return flag;

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="/header.jsp"></jsp:include>

    <%
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //Forces caches 
        //to obtain a new copy of the page from the origin server
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); //Directs caches 
        //not to store the page under any circumstance
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //Causes the proxy cache 
        //to see the page as "stale"
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 backward 
        //compatibility
            response.setHeader("Refresh", "1");
        final String USER = "user";
        final String LOGIN_PAGE = "/login.jsp";
        final int CDEC_HEAD_ID = 74;
        final int FINANCE_HEAD_ID = 552;
        final int UK_OPERATION_HEAD_ID = 115;
        final int QUALITY_HEAD_ID = 55694;
        final int SALES_AND_MARKETING_HEAD_ID = 130;
        final int CHINA_OPERATION_HEAD_ID = 1731;
        final int COE_BU_HEAD = 101;
        final int FINANACE_BU_HEAD = 23;
        final int NBU_FINANCE = 12;
        final int NBU_IT = 15;
        final int NBU_SHARED = 22;
        final int COMPETENCE_HEAD = 13;
        final RequestDispatcher rd = request
        .getRequestDispatcher(LOGIN_PAGE);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute(USER);
        int empId = user.getEmpId();
        String id = String.valueOf(empId);
        if (user == null) {
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    %>

    <form method="post" action="GsrReportManager">
        <!-- name="grossMarginreportForm" id="exitEmpForm"
                        onsubmit="return isValidData();" -->
        <div class="mainalignment">

        <h3 align="left"><B><font color="teal">Create Slab</font></B></h3> 



    <table>
        <!--    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;">
            View Spot Excellence Awards</td>
        </tr> -->

        <tr align="center">
        <td>Year:</td>
        <td><select id="year" name="year">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">-select year-</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
<option value="2025">2025</option>
<option value="2026">2026</option>
<option value="2027">2027</option>
<option value="2028">2028</option>
<option value="2029">2029</option>
<option value="2030">2030</option>

                                </select></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td>Slab:</td>
                                                <option value="-1" selected="selected">-select slab-</option>
<option value="H1">H1</option>
<option value="H2">H2</option>
</select></td>

</tr>
                            <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"><button value="Create" name="Create" onclick="return myFunction()">Create</button>
</tr>

</table></form>
<br><br>
<TABLE cellpadding="2" style=background-color: bgcolor="#d3d3d3" width="400px">
<TBODY>

<TR style="background-color: teal; color: white;">
<TD align="center" width="10px"><b>Year</b></TD>
<TD align="center" width="20px"><b>Rating Slab</b></TD>
</TR>
 <%
try{
slabList = (List)request.getAttribute("slabList");
for (Iterator itr = slabList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) 
{
%>
 <tr><td align="center"><%
Object[] SlabBO = (Object[]) itr.next();
%><%=SlabBO[2] %></td><td align="center"><%=SlabBO[1] %></td></tr>
<% 
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>

  </div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript `myFunction()` is the method where I need my static jsp data "slabList".

Answer (score 0):

Your browser code knows nothing about JSP servlet and vice versa. If you want to use the data in your browser you need to output an array initialization code in your JSP servlet. E.g.:

```
<script>
function myFunction() 
{
 var slabList = [<% 
// output your data from slabList in a JSON format
 %>];

}
```

Alternatively you can create a REST api and load the data on the fly using Ajax, but I guess this would be the next step for you.

Comment: My slabList data is an array of Type Object. How to make that data in JSON format. I don't know anything about JSON.

Comment: the latter approach. There are too many technologies included about which I have no idea.

Comment: is there any other alternative to acheive this?

Comment: @sajjadsohail, JSON is a pretty straightforward text format. You can format your Java Object into JSON yourself or use some JSON library which are many. E.g., here is an example http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/